# Can 't find Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, installation

I was using TB 5.0 then the system requested to upgrade to v 6.0 I tried to installed from the .tar.bz2 file, extracted the files but was not be able to make it run. Then tried to install it through Synaptic Package manager and Ubuntu Software center but I can't find Thunderbird. Is not under "applications" "internet" (I did tried"Edit Menus") etc. 
I can see at Synaptic Package manager that it is installed but can't find it. 
I think parts of the program are still in there so the system didn't recognize the new install. 
Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please let us know how was TB 5.0 was installed. Was it again through a tar.bz file or through Synaptic? Have you added any PPAs to your system?

Then, I suggest you do the following:

- Run a `dpkg -l |grep ^i |grep thunderbird` and post the results here.
  This command will show whether Thunderbird is currently installed through the repositories as well as its version.
- If you want to upgrade to the latest 6.0 version, you could try to add the official PPA by typing: 
  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stable`

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install thunderbird`

Comment: dpkg -l |grep ^i |grep thunderbird   Does not provide any information. I don't remember from where did I install TB. Also when I make a "sudo find / -name Thunderbird" :

Comment: I mean that you should type this command in a shell, press enter and copy/paste the results here ;-)

Comment: Also when I make a "sudo find / -name Thunderbird" : "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/orca/scripts/apps/Thunderbird"    and   "/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/apps/Thunderbird"  come up. Do you think one of those are preventing me the re-installation of TB?  I did add the official PPA a few months ago.

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall thunderbird`

Comment: dpkg command produced: "thunderbird" (in red) and "3.1.11+build2+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1"   I have to say that I did the "reinstall" before (early today I disabled the PPA trying to get an older version just in case was a problem related with v6).

Comment: seems there is something installed (3.1.11) but I cannot see TB nowhere. (as you can see English is not my mother tongue....) BTW I appreciate your help.

Comment: I'd then try a `sudo apt-get -remove --purge thunderbird`. Then, re-enable the PPA and proceed with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install thunderbird` as already posted above.

Comment: ok. did all of that. grep command: "thunderbird 6.0..." seems it is installed, but I still can't see it. Where can I find TB ?

Comment: Try to run `/usr/bin/thunderbird`. Gotta go for now though. Hope it works, otherwise we'll talk tomorrow ;)

Comment: "/usr/bin/thunderbird" worked but the following message come up at Terminal:gustavo@gustavo-laptop:~$ /usr/bin/thunderbird
WARNING: Application calling GLX 1.3 function "glXCreatePixmap" when GLX 1.3 is not supported!  This is an application bug!
WARNING: Application calling GLX 1.3 function "glXDestroyPixmap" when GLX 1.3 is not supported!  This is an application bug!

(thunderbird-bin:1704): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.24.1/gobject/gsignal.c:1149: unable to lookup signal "text-insert" for non instantiatable type `AtkText'

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to get it from the Thunderbird-stable PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stable`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install thunderbird`

Comment: The `.../thunderbird-stable` PPA is no longer in used. (See [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911807).)